# is it possible to display the image with number of times the user need?

Tags: css

I can  able to display the image using background-image in css. But i need to display that image three times repeatedly. there is possibilities for repeat option like background-repeat:repeat-x or repeat-y. Is there any other option like what i need.?

Comment: Three times in one element or in different elements?

Comment: in your example i want a space betwwen them..

Comment: You can't do it in one element at the moment. http://jsfiddle.net/CfU6T/1/ is probably the closest you can get, unless you can edit the gap into your image.

Answer (score 2):

A background image will repeat by default, so you just have to make the element three times as wide as the image to get the background repeated three times.

**Edit:**
If you want a space between the repetitions, you have to include that space in the image.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, this is not possible.

[CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-repeat) will bring some interesting `background-repeat` settings, `repeat`, `space` , `round` and the `background-clip` property that allows limiting the background painting area, but they are not supported across browsers yet.

Depending on what you want to do, there may be a workaroud.